# The appearance of the element only when focusing on the input field using Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, forms

Can someone suggest how to display a pop-up menu `suggestions` with past queries only after the input field `search-form__input` has been selected?

**search.component.html**

```
<div class="search-form mt-2 input-group mb-2">
  <input appShowSuggestions type="search" class="form-control search-form__input"
         placeholder="Поиск (макс. количество найденных статей - 30)" maxlength="60"
         [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
         (keyup)="showArticlesKeyup($event)"
         [formControl]="typeahead"
         (input)="suggest()" >
  <div class="input-  group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary search-form__btn" type="submit"
      (click)="showArticles()" [disabled]="searchQuery.trim() === ''">Искать</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="suggestions" *ngIf="suggestions.length">
  <small class="text-muted">Ваши прошлые запросы:</small>
  <p class="suggestions__link"
     *ngFor="let suggest of suggestions"
     (click)="searchQuery = suggest; showArticles()"> {{ suggest }}</p>
</div>
```

**search.component.ts**

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private articleService: ArticleService) { }

  searchQuery = '';
  articles: any[] = [];
  searchQueryCollection: string[] = [];
  suggestions: string[] = [];
  typeahead: FormControl = new FormControl();


  static getUrl(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&profile=normal&search='
      + searchQuery + '&limit=30&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  suggest() {
    this.suggestions = Array.from(new Set(this.searchQueryCollection))
      .filter(c => c.startsWith(this.typeahead.value))
      .slice(0, 5);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showArticles() {
    this.articleService.getArticles(SearchComponent.getUrl(this.searchQuery))
      .subscribe(
        (data: IArticle) => {
          this.articles = Object.values({ ...data });
          this.searchQueryCollection.push(this.searchQuery);
        }
      );
  }

  showArticlesKeyup(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && this.searchQuery.trim() !== '') {
      this.showArticles();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input appShowSuggestions type="search" class="form-control search-form__input"
         placeholder="Поиск (макс. количество найденных статей - 30)" maxlength="60"
         [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
         (keyup)="showArticlesKeyup($event)"
         [formControl]="typeahead"
         (input)="suggest()" >
```

One suggestion would be to add `(focus)="toggleSuggestions()"` and then toggle suggestions would look like this:

```
toggleSugestions = () => this.showSuggestions = !this.showSuggestions;
```

You would then change your ng if to something like:

```
<div class="suggestions" *ngIf="showSuggestions && suggestions.length">
```

Comment: And how can I hide the pop-up menu if input is not selected, but at the same time perform functions when I click on the pop-up menu item?

Comment: hiding the popup would be adding (blur)="toggleSuggestions()". So when you focus the element the focus event is triggered, when you blur out of it the same method is called, but because the method's side effect `this.showSuggestions = !this.showSuggestions;` , this will always resolve to a boolean opposite of it's current value.

Comment: The menu disappears if input is not selected, but when you try to click on one of the menu items, it just disappears and nothing happens.

Comment: It's been a while, but you may need to adjust the method above to also keep the element in focus. You can do this with @ViewChild. Good artile on how to execut this here:

https://codeburst.io/focusing-on-form-elements-the-angular-way-e9a78725c04f

Comment: This article deals with keeping an input in focus, but the same could be applied to keeping the dropdown in focus.